# Error while creating the chart using highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to create the column chart/Bar chart using CSV data. Here's the data's format:

```
A 156600 154965  45679  184736 160819 42329
B 7271   4537    5379   245    0      1941
C 4347   19143   1075   397    6860   0
D 15     11283   1477   0      0      0
E 6323   537697  222430 21701  98725  3792
F 0      0       0      0      0      0
G 284356 744986  616369 0      0      106877
H 0      0       0      0      0      0
I 0      0       0      32962  0      0
J 0      12742   616    0      0      0
K 0      1215413 1420   0      0      0
L 0      0       0      0      0      0
M 24191  50166   18163  55282  48262  5862
N 0      0       0      0      0      20396
```

Here I will add the X- axis categories manually. So, I want to create the chart like
[the one seen here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic)

I made this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Total Transactions'
        },
        xAxis: {
           categories: [],labels : { y : 20, rotation: -45, align: 'right' }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Units'
            }
        },
        series: []
    };

    $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
        // Split the lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');
                var series = { 
                    name: 'Transactions ',
                    data: []
                };
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {

            var items = line.split(',');
            if (lineNo != 0) {
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo == 0) {
                            options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                        } else if (itemNo == 2){

                            series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                        }
                });
            }

        });
        options.series.push(series);
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});
```

But it's taking the column wise value means:

```
156600
7271    
4347    
15  
6323    
0   
284356
0   
0   
0   
0   
0   
24191   
0
```

But I need this instead:

- For A (like Jan), the value should be

  ```
  156600 154965 45679 184736  160819  42329
  ```
- For B (Like Feb), another column should have the values:

  ```
  7271 4537   5379    245 0   1941
  ```

Can you please help me out?

Comment: If the letters represent the months of a year, then you have to many letters.  There are only 12 months in a year.  However, you have 14 letters.  What does the letters M and N represent?

Comment: Really hard to tell what your data looks like because your sample data is not comma separated but your code is splitting on ','. It also looks like your sample data is just one long string - not split into rows/new lines. Is this true? If A is "Like Jan" then why not call it "Jan"?

Comment: By looking at it, I am guessing that you are needing 6 separate series.  Am I correct?  It looks as if you are only creating one series in your code.

Comment: Ok, let me explain  :   Month,India,China,Australia,Shreelanka,US,Cuba
Jan,156600,154965,45679,184736,160819,42329
Feb,7271,4537,5379,245,0,1941
March,4347,19143,1075,397,6860,0
 Now using above data i need to create chart as same mentioned in the below link-http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic
In above chart , Jan shows for Tokeyo,New york,london,and berlin together ....similer to this form my data for Jan i need to create the colums for India,China,Austrelia,Shrilanka,US,Cuba

as same as chart in the link http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic...

Comment: So you do want 6 seperate series included in the chart.  So, row A represents January and L represents December.  All of the letter in between represent the months in between.  So what does row M and N represent?

Comment: **@Akshay Khamkar**, What is the status of this question?  Did you get it figured out, did you give up, or do you need further assistance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have it now you will end up with 14 series each containing 6 data points. What you really need to do if you can is alter the csv file so that your columns represent the month and the rows represent the series like so:
[image]

Then you can create a array for each row and pass the array to the highchart.  I think your code should work with the above csv structure, since you are performing the split based on \n.

**EDIT**

If you can not change the format of your CSV file then the below modified code should build the 6 series as you need them.  It assumes that there is no headers for the columns or the rows.  It also ignores the last two rows which extend beyond the 12 months of a year.

```
$.get('data.csv', function(data) {
  var lines = data.split('\n');
  var series1 = {name: 'India', data: []};
  var series2 = {name: 'China', data: []};
  var series3 = {name: 'Australia', data: []};
  var series4 = {name: 'Shreelanka', data: []};
  var series5 = {name: 'US', data: []};
  var series6 = {name: 'Cuba', data: []};

  $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
    var items = line.split(',');
    //IGNORE THE LAST TWO ROWS
    if (lineNo < 12) {
      $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
        if (itemNo == 0) {
          series1.data.push(parseFloat(item)); 
        } else if (itemNo == 1){
          series2.data.push(parseFloat(item));
        } else if (itemNo == 2){
          series3.data.push(parseFloat(item));
        } else if (itemNo == 3){
          series4.data.push(parseFloat(item));
        } else if (itemNo == 4){
          series5.data.push(parseFloat(item));
        } else if (itemNo == 5){
          series6.data.push(parseFloat(item));
        }
      });
    }
  });
  options.series.push(series1);
  options.series.push(series2);
  options.series.push(series3);
  options.series.push(series4);
  options.series.push(series5);
  options.series.push(series6);
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Comment: Thanks....you got my problem... we will ignore the M and N.I have tried a lot but not able to get the expected results, can you please what i need to modify in above code.

Comment: If you can modify the CSV file so that it is in the above format that I displayed for you then your code should work as is.  I would actually check to see if that is possible.  If so, everything will be cleaner and easier for you.  If you manually create a file with the above format and run it through your program you will see what I mean.

Comment: If you cannot change the organization of the CSV file then see my edited answer.

Comment: Hi Linger....i tried it today..first thing hats off to you the way you explained me it really awesome..basically i am from mainframe so its quit difficult to me , but the way you explained, i am clear now...It worked perfectly..Thank You Linger..!!

Comment: Your welcome.  If my answer worked please _vote up_ and mark it as the accepted answer.  Please see [**How To Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if you don't know how to _vote up_ or mark a question as accepted.